# Why Do Some Desktop Websites Turn Into Mobile-Mode On Certain Zoom In Percent?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, mobile-phone

For example, when I go to [this website](http://urbanedge.blogs.rice.edu/) on my desktop and zoom in to 300% the website appears to turn into mobile-mode. A menu button appears around 300% zoom (Google Chrome with a  1920 x 1080 screen resolution).

Is this how mobile-mode or mobile-sites are activated - is it the screen resolution?

Comment: This is called responsive design.  In the css of the site are rules that cause different layout decisions to be made depending on the width of the viewport.  As you scale down your browser, you are triggering layouts intended for a phone.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is this how mobile-mode or mobile-sites are activated - is it the screen resolution?**

Yes, this is how many websites adapt themselves to fit into the available space.

See [Responsive Web Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

A typical way to achieve this would be to have something like the following in CSS

```
 /* ======== Styling common to all sized devices ======== */
 ...
 /* ========= Styling for desktops ===================== */
 @media screen and (min-width: 901px) {
 ...
 /* ========= Styling for tablets ===================== */
 @media screen and (min-width: 671px) and (max-width: 900px) {
 ...
```

Where the bulk of the CSS (say 95%) is in the first section, which by itself is suitable for phones. This is overridden
in later sections to rearrange menus and unhide optional sidebars etc.

So if you resize your desktop browser's window to be the same size (in pixels) as your mobile phone screen - you would expect to see the same mobile-optimised website layout.

Modern browsers try very hard to do the "right thing" when you zoom in. Even though the window hasn't changed size, they are magnifying the content and they recognize that this is, in some way, equivalent to reducing the window size - So they reinterpret the CSS accordingly.

Not all websites work this may, many still try to detect the actual device or browser and make choices based on that - this is an approach that needs continual maintenance as new devices and new browsers are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the website is coded, but usually it's to do with the 'virtual' resolution - the resolution of which the web browser is at at different zoom levels. So a 300% zoom at 1920 x 1080 turns it into an area of 640 x 360. This resolution is most likely picked up by the webpage as a 'mobile' resolution - hence, it feeds you the mobile version.